# Cannot Script to file in h2 database in java application

Tags: java, exception, h2, database-backups

When I tried to backup my database by `org.h2.tools.Script.process()`, I keep getting a wired problem, in which it did not mention the details :

```
    org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SCRIPT  TO '' TEST[*].SQL "; SQL statement:
SCRIPT  TO '' test.sql [42000-194]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:191)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:532)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:259)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:564)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:505)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1204)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:170)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:158)
    at org.h2.tools.Script.process(Script.java:139)
    at com.h2.examples.Example.generatBackup(Example.java:57)
    at com.h2.examples.Example.main(Example.java:40)
```

My sample code:

```
private static final String DB_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";
  private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:h2:~/test";
  private static final String DB_USER = "";
  private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Example example = new Example();

    try {
      Connection connection = getDBConnection();

      example.generatBackup(connection, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, "test.sql");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private void generatBackup(Connection connection,
                             String user,
                             String password,
                             String fileName) throws SQLException {
    Script.process(connection, user, password, fileName);
  }
```

}

Environment:

Windows 10

Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

H2 1.4.194

Comment: Come on, any comment is appreciated! Or should I provide any further information? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was using h2 1.4.197 and seems your usage of parameter order is incorrect. Please have a look at the following [API Method](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/version-1.4.197/h2/src/main/org/h2/tools/Script.java#L134) for usage of the process API.

process(Connection conn,String fileName, String options1, String options2)